# Union on simple MySQL recursion

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, union

Is there a way to do a UNION between the LEFT JOIN lines, so that the results are not in a separate columns (lev1, lev2, lev3 and lev4), but in a single column (i.e. "ItemNo")?

Here's the MySQL query:

```
SELECT t1.ItemID AS lev1, t2.ItemID as lev2, t3.ItemID as lev3, t4.ItemID as lev4
FROM TableOfRelations AS t1
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t2 ON t2.ParentItemID = t1.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t3 ON t3.ParentItemID = t2.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t4 ON t4.ParentItemID = t3.ItemID
WHERE t1.ParentItemID = (SELECT ID FROM TableOfItems WHERE ItemID = 3599);
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a sample of result I am looking for:

```
ItemID   ParentItemID   JoinedDescription1      JoinedDescription2
  3599      NULL        MyString1A              MyString1B
  35        3599       MyString35A             MyString35B
  168       3599        MyString168A            MyString168B
  192       168         MyString192A            MyString192B
  238       3599        MyString238A            MyString238B
  266       168         MyString266A            MyString266B
```

This result will be used for filling up a TreeView using VB.NET. Also the "JoinedDescriptions" are yet to be joined from a different table according to ItemID, but I think I can handle that easily once I get the basic table correctly.
Important note: Those selected lines are only belonging to one item (root item "3599" in this example), meaning it's only few lines out of thousands. Some recursion examples presume that all the table lines are used in the query, which is not my case.

Comment: What would be the output you're seeking?  Can you show a simple 4 row input table (where one of the rows has ItemID 3599 and the others are the parent items upwards), and your desired output?  What do you want if the item is at the second level in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a query as below.

```
select t1.ItemID as ItemNo
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t2 ON t2.ParentItemID = t1.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t3 ON t3.ParentItemID = t2.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t4 ON t4.ParentItemID = t3.ItemID
WHERE t1.ParentItemID = (SELECT ID FROM TableOfItems WHERE ItemID = 3599)
UNION
select t2.ItemID as ItemNo
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t2 ON t2.ParentItemID = t1.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t3 ON t3.ParentItemID = t2.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t4 ON t4.ParentItemID = t3.ItemID
WHERE t1.ParentItemID = (SELECT ID FROM TableOfItems WHERE ItemID = 3599)
UNION
select t3.ItemID as ItemNo
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t2 ON t2.ParentItemID = t1.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t3 ON t3.ParentItemID = t2.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t4 ON t4.ParentItemID = t3.ItemID
WHERE t1.ParentItemID = (SELECT ID FROM TableOfItems WHERE ItemID = 3599)
UNION
select t4.ItemID as ItemNo
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t2 ON t2.ParentItemID = t1.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t3 ON t3.ParentItemID = t2.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableOfRelations AS t4 ON t4.ParentItemID = t3.ItemID
WHERE t1.ParentItemID = (SELECT ID FROM TableOfItems WHERE ItemID = 3599)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, seems feasible, altouhgh I will have to add more JOINs due to more information linked to the base entries, which means it will grow even further. But I tested the query and seems to work well!

Comment: I agree, with these many joins you may not achieve a good performance if you have a larger database.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not really a way to do a UNION between the LEFT JOIN operations.

But you can use the resultset from your query to get the result you want, by turning your query into an inline view.

Here's one way:

```
SELECT u.i AS lev
     , CASE u.i
       WHEN 1 THEN t.lev1
       WHEN 2 THEN t.lev2
       WHEN 3 THEN t.lev3
       WHEN 4 THEN t.lev4
       END AS levItemID
  FROM ( SELECT 1 AS i
         UNION ALL SELECT 2
         UNION ALL SELECT 3
         UNION ALL SELECT 4
       ) u
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT t1.ItemID AS lev1
              , t2.ItemID AS lev2
              , t3.ItemID AS lev3
              , t4.ItemID AS lev4
           FROM TableOfItems t0
           JOIN TableOfRelations t1
             ON t1.ParentItemID = t0.id
           LEFT
           JOIN TableOfRelations t2
             ON t2.ParentItemID = t1.ItemID
           LEFT
           JOIN TableOfRelations t3
             ON t3.ParentItemID = t2.ItemID
           LEFT
           JOIN TableOfRelations t4
             ON t4.ParentItemID = t3.ItemID
          WHERE t0.ItemID = 3599
       ) t
```

**Note:** this is really more of a UNION ALL operation, it doesn't remove duplicates, it returns NULL values, and it returns the level of the parent.

You can tweak the query to get the results you want. If you don't care about the level number, remove the `u.i` from the SELECT list.

To remove duplicates, you can either add the DISTINCT keyword following SELECT, or add a GROUP BY clause. To eliminate NULL values, you can add a `HAVING levItemID IS NOT NULL` clause, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for concatenating strings.

See the Mysql Documentation on Concat:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want the itemID on leaf nodes (I see no mention of itemNo in your query)....

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(t4.ItemID, IFNULL(t3.ItemID, IFNULL(t2.ItemID, t1.ItemId))    
(+remainder of your query)
```

Comment: After trying all the suggestions, surprisingly, this is the best solution! Thanks for advice!